# Newly created objects don't render in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, object

I'm just learning Flash/Actionscript 3 and I'm trying to create a new object using an object already placed in the scene, and this is the code for it:

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

public class Scene1 extends MovieClip
{
    {
        {
            {
                var theRoot:MovieClip = MovieClip(root);
                var mouse:mouse1 = new mouse1();


                //Scene1(void);
                //onClipEvent(30);


                function Scene1():void
                {               this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, Joe);



                }


                public function Joe(event:MouseEvent):void
                {
                    mouse.x = mouseX;
                    mouse.y = mouseY;
                    mouse.x = 160;
                    mouse.y = 160;
                    trace(mouse.x + " " + mouse.y + " " + mouse.z);
                }
            }
        }
        }}};
```

It does trace the position as it should be (160,160), bu object doesn't render, even if I change Z.. although, there aren't any objects that would be blocking it in their view anyway.

This is mouse1:

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


public class mouse1 extends MovieClip
{
    {
        {
            var theRoot:MovieClip = MovieClip(root);


            mouse1(void);
            //onClipEvent(30);


            function mouse1():void
            {
                //this.z = -20;

                trace("WROKZZZ");
            }


            public function Joe(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                //this.x = mouseX;
                //this.y = mouseY;
            }
        }
    }
    }};
```

Comment: you haven't added the mouse object to the display list. try `addChild(mouse);` after `var mouse:mouse1 = new mouse1();` or all in one line: `var mouse:mouse1 = addChild(new mouse1()) as mouse1;`

Comment: i tried that and it said that it was an unidentified function, then i tried this.addChild in the Scene1 function and it didn't seem to do anything :/

Comment: Where is the class of `mouse1`? What does that look like?

Comment: added it to the main post thing

Comment: have you linked mouse1 class to a library item?

Comment: well, i had a graphic and i did "Convert to Symbol" and created the AS file from that. And the symbol works if i place it in the editor, but not if i created.

Comment: @NeHatchickVerma Scene1 is a MovieClip subclass which is a subclass of DisplayObjectContainer, therefore it should inherit the `addChild()` method. Are you getting any errors (at runtime or otherwise) that might prevent that part of the code from running ? also, is there a Scene1 instance added to the main display list ?

Comment: the Scene1 is an object that is placed in the editor and it renders, so I guess it is. No errors besides the 'no define function', but no such error if i do this.addChild(), but that does nothing.

Comment: Is it just me or does it look like you have too many {}s in your class definitions? Also, try stage.addChild(mouse) instead.

Comment: @xiaodili stage.addChild(mouse) worked!! Add that as an answer!

Comment: good stuff, glad it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As well as creating the object with `new`, it needs to be added to the display list (see here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/display_list_programming_as3.html) before it is rendered, so use `stage.addChild(mouse)` to do this.